# Recover files from earlier git merge that reverted commits

Tags: git

I am in weird state right now.

During some mistaken merge, coleague made a commit that reverted all changes from one of the parents, but it is still taken as a parent to that commit.

Some more commits happened after this wrong merge and now we found out. What to do now?

We cannot merge the current master with the "deleted" commit, because it, technically, is an ancestor. What to do now?

Answer (score 0):

That was easy.

`git-revert -m 2` on the erroneous merge worked perfectly.