# Revert some file/directory deletions from other Revert, Recover file and directory from Commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-commit, revert, file-recovery

I made a revert that deleted some files and **directories**... According to the The screenshot:

The `Red` box shows the commit with my revert.
The `Blue` arrow shows the position inside of my project
The Green arrows shows the files that I would like to recover...

I see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865630/recover-files-from-earlier-git-merge-that-reverted-commits), but that is recovering all, and this [How do I reset or revert a file to a specific revision?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215718/how-do-i-reset-or-revert-a-file-to-a-specific-revision) shows only file.
This [Git revert just some files in commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36201607/811293) is about single file.

**How I Could do the recovery with `directory`?**

[image]

**Is it possible do this operation directly from `IntelliJ`?**

[image]

**Is it possible do this operation interactively (in order to select what recover)?**

Comment: [Does this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670745/how-to-restore-a-whole-directory-from-history-of-git-repository) sound like what you are trying to do?

Comment: You can click on 'Cherry-pick selected changes' and then remove undesired changes from Change List and commit only those that you consider useful.